# db:migrate - Duplicate column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

I execute migrations:db  on production server.  MySQL is DB, I got this error :

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'imported': ALTER TABLE `projects` ADD `imported` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL

migration as below :

```
class AddImprotedToProject < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :imported, :boolean, default: false, null: false
  end    
end
```

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a good post for StackOverflow (as it's not even a question). I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

try to do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't try this option as thinking,it will drop the data in schema in the production database.  I observed db/schema.rb with the latest version, which is related to this migrate. Not able to understand, why the  error still persists ?

Comment: Addition to above comment :  Even manually  deleted the column in the database. Execution of  db:migrate was fine. But gitlab:check says to execute db:migrate to fix the issue.